# Does taking protein supplements help the vocal folds recover?

Tags: vocal-cords

I have recently begun practising vocal training/singing daily after years of not doing any of it.

However, my vocal cords always feel "tired" after some 45 minutes to 1 hour of practising. This span has been increasing slowly as I practise, but I really feel like it's a bottleneck. I'm pretty sure I'm singing with proper technique, since I had many years of singing lessons and it still feels very natural. This is to say I don't think I'm putting any strain on the vocal cords and they really are just tired and not "hurt", per se.

I know hydration is of utmost importance, but I was wondering whether, since the vocal cords are muscle tissue, upping my protein intake via supplements might help recovery.

It may be worth mentioning that I am already on a healthy diet and also take whey protein from time to time as it helps a lot with muscle recovery from my workouts.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we're not doctors, we're musicians.

Comment: @Tetsujin hello! Is there any other site on the network where you think it'd be appropriate for me to ask this question?

Comment: There's https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/ or maybe https://fitness.stackexchange.com/ but I really don't know their criteria for questions.

Comment: BTW… I'm always amused by "hydration is of utmost importance" as I've never ever heard anyone over 30 ever say that. I just can't imagine anyone shouting over at Roger Daltrey, "Did you make sure to bring your water bottle?" Similarly whey protein shakes & smoothies.. it's a whole new world… inhabited only by the young. Personally, on stage I've always just used beer for "hydration" & whisky "for my vocal folds". Protein supplement depends on whether you can get a curry, burger or fried chicken at 4am. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the suggestions! Regarding hydration, I'd suggest taking a look at [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2925668/) article. Take care of your voice! As to the protein supplements, I used to have the same perception until I had to train 6x a week and fight every other weekend. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, but even if it helps, it won’t help as much as **sleep**. Your muscles recover most while you are asleep.

Dietary protein has an effect on a long time scale. The only dietary ingredient that I know of that has a recovery affect on muscles is sugar and simple starches, but I’m almost positive that is not relevant to musical muscles.

During strength or endurance training of large muscles, glycogen that is stored in those muscles is broken down to provide energy that is close at hand. If the training continues long enough, the glycogen runs out and cortisol is released to begin the process of breaking down actual muscle tissue to provide energy. Sadly fat takes to long to break down into energy for it to be used during an actual workout, so when your body is out of glycogen, the muscles are next to go. Cortisol causes the shakes that you might experience after an intense workout. It also is what causes marathon runners to simply go limp at a certain point. If you’ve worked out to the point where you body has released cortisol, then if you ingest sugars and or simple starches your body will release insulin to enable the uptake of the resulting serum glucose. Insulin shuts down cortisol, so you can stop the shakes and prevent further muscle breakdown by ingesting sugars, especially in liquid form. Ingesting protein at this point would not arrest the cortisol reaction and would slow down the metabolism of glucose. Protein will be needed in the hours after an intense workout to rebuild the muscles, and the muscles will be rebuilt more during sleep than any other time.

Since a long vocal workout does not involve large enough muscle groups, it’s very unlikely you are running out of glycogen and releasing cortisol. Recovery for fine muscles is all about a balanced diet, hydration, and sleep, sleep, sleep. Cross training with reasonable aerobic exercise is also good for general health and the fine muscles.

Note that even professional singers generally don’t sing more than 1.5 hours without a break. If you want to get more total practice time in during a day, the best way is to break it up into multiple shorter sessions with breaks in between. This applies to all musical training. You might be able to do an hour in the morning and an hour in the evening.

Either way, be very careful about pushing yourself. Building stamina for *any* activity takes a **long** time. If you were able to add an average of one minute per day to your practice I would find that to be reasonable. Endurance training out side of music usually doesn’t add more than 10% per week, if that. The more you want to maximize your singing ability, the more it makes sense to hire a professional teacher to help you gauge appropriate progress and avoid injury.

Seems like you are a few years older than last time you sang daily. Everything changes as we age. It takes longer to recover. Your muscles need more sleep. It takes longer to build up stamina. You might be in your late 20s and already things will take longer than they did when you were 19-23. And a teacher is still valuable - perhaps even more so as we age.

Comment: This was an excellent read, much appreciated! Cheers :)